# How to display data with radio buttons based on drop down selection?

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql

I'm trying to dynamically generate radio buttons with data in front of them. The data that is to be displayed in front of the radio button is based on a drop down selection, which also displays some data in a text box using javascript.

I tried taking the selected option in a string and use it in the next query, but I know I am doing it wrong.

Database Connection

```
$db = pg_connect("");
$query = "select account_name,account_code,address1,address2,address3 FROM 
customers";
$result = pg_query($db,$query);
```

//NEW QUERY

```
 $sql1= "select name from conferences";
      $result1= pg_query($db, $sql1);
```

//END

//New Code

```
 <select class="form-control" id="conference"  name="conference">
 <option value="">Select Conference...</option>
 <?php while($rows1 = pg_fetch_assoc($result1)) { ?>
    <option value="<?= $rows1['code']; ?>"><?= $rows1['name']; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
 </select>
                <br>
```

// END OF NEW CODE

Dropdown to select the data.

```
<select onchange="ChooseContact(this)" class="form-control" 
id="account_name"  name="account_name" >

<?php
while($rows= pg_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
echo  '<option value=" '.$rows['address1'].'  '.$rows['address2'].' 
'.$rows['address3'].''.$rows['account_code'].'">'.$rows['account_name'].' 
'.$_POST[$rows['account_code']].' 
</option>';
}?>
</select>
```

Displaying data in the text area based on the selcted value using javascript. (The code works fine till here)

```
<textarea readonly class="form-control" style="background-color: #F5F5F5;" 
id="comment" rows="5" style="width:700px;"value=""placeholder="Address..."> 
</textarea>
                <script>
                function ChooseContact(data) {
document.getElementById ("comment").value = data.value;
            }
                </script>
```

Displaying data in front of the radio buttons based on the selected option(This code works if I use some random value in the query, but not if I use the selected value 'account_code' from the previous query. I'm using POST GET method to carry the selected value)

```
 <?php
```

//NEW CODE

```
 $sql = "select  order_number, order_date from orders where 
 customer_account_code =  '3000614' and conference_code='DS19-'"; <-Data 
 gets displayed when put random value like this.

 $code = $_GET[$rows['account_code']];
 $conf = $_GET[$rows1['conference_code']];
 $sql = "select  order_number, order_date from orders where 
customer_account_code = '$code' and conference_code= '$conf']"; <- But I 
want to display the data against the selected value, i.e, the 'account_code' 
in the variable $code from the dropdown select
```

//END

```
$res = pg_query($db,$sql);

while($value = pg_fetch_assoc($res) ){
echo "<input type='radio' name='answer' 
value='".$value['order_number']." ".$value['order_date']."'>" 
.$value['order_number'].$value['order_date']." </input><br />";
                    }
                    ?>
```

I need to help to find a way to put the selected 'account_code' in a variable and use it in the $sql query.

Comment: please add in your question, the problem - tell me if your first code works for example :)  and tell me if you use AJAX ?

Comment: I have the updated the question, and no friend, I don't have much experience with ajax.

Comment: About 'account_code' in your question, you mean 'account_name'  from **select** options ? you want to get account_name from selected option and run your query after submit ? for example ?

Comment: No, the last the concatenated value in the option value=" . $rows['account_code']."

Comment: You want to get account_name from selected option and run your query after submitting? for example?

Comment: Hi, I have now concatenated 'account_code' to the select code and have updated the question with the POST GET method that I have been trying. Kindly let me know if its possibly that way.

Comment: Ahh! Good! I will create an AJAX code now to get these values without updating the page & from selected option **account_code** ;) - Please min ...

Comment: You seem to think that PHP can run code *after* the user has interacted with the page (by making a selection). This is a misunderstanding. If you want PHP to do something, you need to send a request from the client (browser/JavaScript) to the server (PHP). Look into the many questions about how to interact with PHP in that way ([google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=run+PHP+when+user+clicks))

Comment: I tried to create a table [like yours](https://imgur.com/a/2h78fPS), and if try to run SQL like yours, I [get that](https://imgur.com/a/NcAljjJ), but I do not understand, there is something strange, are you trying to get a **customer_account_code** and where **customer_account_code** that you will not get anything other than **customer_account_code** in the results? Do you understand me?

Comment: Hi. 'account_code' is from the table 'customers', and 'customer_account_code' is from the table 'orders'. They both have same values from different table, that is why I want to put the selected 'account_code' and match it with 'customer_account_code' in the new query. And yes you are right. The output I want is a concatenation of two other data. I have updated the code with the same. Sorry!

Comment: AAh! Now good ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this code : (It's work for me)

1- Add this line to your HTML `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

2- Edit your CODE to this:

**Dropdown to select the data:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="account_name"  name="account_name">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php while($rows = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $rows['address1'].' '.$rows['address2'].' '.$rows['address3'].'-'.$rows['account_code']; ?>"><?= $rows['account_name']; ?></option>
    <? } ?>
</select>
```

**Displaying data in the text area based on the selected value using jQuery:**

```
<textarea readonly class="form-control" style="background-color: #F5F5F5;" 
id="comment" rows="5" style="width:700px;" value="" placeholder="Address..."></textarea>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#comment').val($('#account_name').val()); // MAKE A DEFAULT VALUE
(function($) {
    $('#account_name').change(function() {
        $('#results').html(''); // REMOVE THE OLD RESULTS 
        var option = $(this).val();
        $('#comment').val(option);
        // EDIT RADIO WITH AJAX 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "path/test.php",
            dataType:'JSON',
            data: $('#account_name').serialize()
        }).done(function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                // ADD RADIO TO DIV RESULTS
                $('#results').append('<input type="radio" name="answer" value="'+data[i].order_number+'">'+data[i].order_date+'</input><br>');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

after that, add this HTML to your page, **to show RESULTS FROM AJAX DATA**

```
<!-- RADIOs -->
<div id="results"></div>
```

3- Create a new file like **path/test.php**

in this file, use this CODE to return values **with JSON** :)

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

// CONNECT (JUST USE YOUR CUSTOM CONNECTION METHOD & REQUIRE CONFIG FILE IF YOU WANT)
$db = pg_connect("");

$value = explode('-', $_POST['account_name']);

// EXPLODE AND GET LAST NUMBER AFTER < - >
$code = (int) end($value);

$sql = "select order_number, order_date from orders where customer_account_code =  '$code'";

$res = pg_query($db, $sql);

// CREATE JSON RESULTS
$is = '';
while($data = pg_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $is .= json_encode($data).', ';
}

// AND GET ALL 
echo '['.substr($is, 0, -2).']';
?>
```

Comment: Hi. I tried the code, it's not working :( There is no error message, but the radio buttons are not getting displayed.

Comment: I think from SQL, I've updated this code - please try and use your connection settings - Try to open your **path/test.php** and use a $code = 2; for example and see if you get any data ;)

Comment: Please re-check my code, It's work but makes sure you use the correct path [here](https://imgur.com/a/nLF92Qq), because I've [tested](https://imgur.com/a/rxZccYx), & everything GOOD, If it's work, please tell me, It took me a lot of time, I hope it works and helps you :)

Comment: For the second time, I've [tested](https://imgur.com/a/IeWCfxk) & with your question data like: Date, id ....  ;)

Comment: Hi Sir. I'm really sorry I couldn't revert. My work hours were over. I'm working on the code you wrote. Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Can you kindly tell me if I want to add another select filter before the first select, how do I do it?

Comment: Just tell me what do you mean :) ? - Add another question if you want, and send his URL ;)

Comment: HI. Kindly check the question. I have updated with markings //NEW AND //END

Comment: No, I tell you to create a new question with my code and your question or problem :)

Comment: HI, this is the link to the new question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54023602/add-two-select-filters-and-carry-the-value-selected-in-the-radio-button-in-a-var