# Add two select filters and carry the value selected in the radio button in a variable

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql

I'm trying to add another select filter to an already working code, and carry the displayed radio button data in a variable to use it in further queries.

//Database connection and queries.

```
$db = pg_connect("");
$query = "select account_name,account_code,address1,address2,address3 FROM 
customers;";
$result = pg_query($db,$query);
$sql1= "select name, code from conferences";
$result1= pg_query($db, $sql1);
```

//Select code which is not working

```
<select class="form-control" id="conference"  name="conference">
<option value="">Select Conference...</option>
<?php while($rows1 = pg_fetch_assoc($result1)) { ?>
    <option value="<?= '-'.$rows1['code']; ?>"><?= $rows1['name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

//Working select code

```
<select class="form-control" id="account_name"  name="account_name">
<option value="">Select Customer...</option>
<?php while($rows = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <option value="<?= $rows['address1'].' '.$rows['address2'].' 
'.$rows['address3'].'-'.$rows['account_code']; ?>"><?= 
$rows['account_name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

<textarea readonly class="form-control" style="background-color: #F5F5F5;" 
id="comment" rows="5" style="width:700px;" value="" 
placeholder="Address..."></textarea>
```

//Javascript code for account_name select.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('#comment').val($('#account_name').val()); // MAKE A DEFAULT VALUE
 (function($) {
 $('#account_name').change(function() {
 $('#results').html(''); // REMOVE THE OLD RESULTS 
 var option = $(this).val();
 $('#comment').val(option);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        dataType:'JSON',
        data: $('#account_name').serialize()
    }).done(function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 // ADD RADIO TO DIV RESULTS
            $('#results').append('<input type="radio" name="radio" 
value="'+data[i].order_number+'">&nbsp; &nbsp;<label> 
<b>'+data[i].order_number+' &nbsp;&nbsp;'+data[i].order_date+'</b></label> 
</input><br>');
        }
    });
});
})(jQuery);           
</script>

<div id="results"></div>
```

//Carry the selected radiobutton value on button click

```
<button id="myBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-success">New Order</button>
```

//Test.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$db = pg_connect();
$value = explode('-', $_POST['account_name']);
$code = (int) end($value);
```

//SOMETHING SIMILAR NEEDS TO BE DONE WITH CONFERENCE.

```
$value1 = explode('-', $_POST['conference']);
$conf = (int) end($value1);
```

//

```
$sql = "select order_number, order_date from orders where 
customer_account_code =  '$code' and conference_code = '$conf'";
$res = pg_query($db, $sql);
$is = '';
while($data = pg_fetch_assoc($res)) {
$is .= json_encode($data).', ';
}
echo '['.substr($is, 0, -2).']';
?>
```

I would like to know how I can modify the script so the first select filter will also work like the latter, and put the displayed radio button data in a variable to use it in further sql queries.

Comment: What should happen when selecting conference?

Comment: HI saif. I have updated the code with what needs to be done with conference. Kindly look into it.